# Remove a reference with a commit message on GitHub?

Tags: github, command, commit

It is possible to reference a issue from an other issue with:

```
reference #xxx
```

Is it somehow possible to delete a reference from a issue with a commit? (like this one:)

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Sure, but it requires rewriting the commit history, and that's considered bad behavior on a public repo.

But, if you decide to, just edit the commit and force push

```
git commit --amend
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: -1. Changing the commit message results in a new commit, so the reference will remain.